# Reading function in C with structure and txt file

Tags: c, file

Can someone help me write a function to read from a .txt file. I made all of this, and I wrote a lot of different functions to read from file, but none of them worked. Every time I pressed option 2, it didn't show me what I wrote to file. Code works without errors, I am just out of ideas how to write a reading function.

Header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H


typedef struct tenant {
    char fname[30];
    char lname[30];
    int floor;
    int phone;
}TENANT;



void write(FILE*, int, TENANT*);


#endif
```

Source.c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>


int main() {

    int n = 0, helper = 0;
    char nameFile[100];
    TENANT *tenant = NULL;
    tenant = (TENANT*)calloc(200, sizeof(TENANT));
    FILE *file = NULL;


    printf("Name of building: ");
    scanf("%s", nameFile);
    printf("\n");

    while (n != 4) {
        printf("Press 1 for creating file! \n");
        printf("Press 2 for reading from file! \n");
        printf("Press 3 for adding new tenants! \n");
        printf("Press 4 to close the file! \n\n");
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("\n");

        switch (n)
        {
        case 1:
            file = fopen(nameFile, "w");
            printf("File created.\n");
            printf("\n");
            fclose(file);
            break;

        case 2:
            if ((file = fopen(nameFile, "r")) == NULL)
            {
                printf("File is not yet created!\n\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                file = fopen(nameFile, "r");
                read(file, helper, tenant);
                printf("\n");
                fclose(file);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            helper++;
            printf("Insert details of tenant: \n", helper);
            file = fopen(nameFile, "a");
            write(file, helper, tenant);
            printf("\n");
            fclose(file);
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("Program closed!\n");
            break;

        default:
            break;

        }
    }
    free(tenant);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Functions.c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Header.h"

void write(FILE* file, int helper, TENANT* tenant) {

    int i = helper - 1;
    printf("Name of tenant: ");
    scanf("%s", (tenant + i)->fname);

    printf("Laste name of tenant: ");
    scanf("%s", (tenant + i)->lname);

    printf("Floor: ");
    scanf("%d", &(tenant + i)->floor);

    printf("Phone: ");
    scanf("%d", &(tenant + i)->phone);

    fprintf(file, "Name: %s\nLast name: %s\nFloor: %d\nPhone: 0%d\n", (tenant + i)->fname, (tenant + i)->lname, (tenant + i)->floor, (tenant + i)->phone);
    fprintf(file, "\n//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n");

}

void read(FILE* file, int helper, TENANT* tenant)
{

    fread(tenant, sizeof(*tenant), 1, file);
    for (int i = 0; i < helper; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file, "Name: %s\nLast name: %s\nFloor: %d\nPhone: 0%d\n", (tenant + i)->fname, (tenant + i)->lname, (tenant + i)->floor, (tenant + i)->phone);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question states that if you press option 2, it doesn't show you the file you created. The code you provided doesn't implement anything for the option 2.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a `read` function that does the opposite of your `write` function? It's basically going to be a chain of `fscanf` calls that look a lot like the `scanf` calls you have in `write` (you're just reading from `file` instead of from `stdin`, and skipping over some extra characters you added to your format), and `printf` calls that look a lot like the `fprintf` (you're just writing to `stdout` instead of `file`, and maybe using a slightly different format). So if you were able to write this `write`, you should be able to write the `read`.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a do my homework service. BTW, the `read` name is conflicting with POSIX [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/read.html) and its [Windows variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/posix-read) so is a bit confusing. I recommend using some different name.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ohh I know this is not a HW service. I am doing this because I like to practice, and trying to improve. This is my idea and, if I stuck on something I will come to Stack Overflow community, and I expect from community to tell me what's wrong and what to change and what to work on. I'm sorry for leaving a bad impression. And also thanks for telling me to use different name. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not name your function write() because there is system call named write(), see man 2 write. Same for read.

There are some bugs you should be aware of, maybe compile your code with -Wall so you can see.
There is no %d in your format for printf() function, yet you passed it variable helper.

```
printf("Insert details of tenant: \n", helper);
```

In your read() function you dont need this line of code

```
fread(tenant, sizeof(*tenant), 1, file);
```

There are many problems with this. You shoud read man 3 fread to see how it works.

So, just make your read function like this

```
void read(FILE* file, int helper, TENANT* tenant)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < helper; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file, "Name: %s\nLast name: %s\nFloor: %d\nPhone: 0%d\n",     (tenant + i)->fname, (tenant + i)->lname, (tenant + i)->floor, (tenant + i)->phone);
    }
}
```

In your main program i think you will have problems with variable helper.
You initialized it in main function like this

```
int helper=0;
```

So first time you call write function you will pass variable helper with value 0, and inside of function your indexer i will start from -1. This will cause index out of range and undefined program behaviour.
Maybe you should initialize helper to be 1 from the start.
After every call to read or write function increment helper so you will not overwrite tenant[0].

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct tenant {
char fname[30];
char lname[30];
int floor;
int phone;
}TENANT;


void write(FILE* file, int helper, TENANT* tenant) {

int i = helper - 1;
printf("Name of tenant: ");
scanf("%s", (tenant + i)->fname);

printf("Laste name of tenant: ");
scanf("%s", (tenant + i)->lname);

printf("Floor: ");
scanf("%d", &(tenant + i)->floor);

printf("Phone: ");
scanf("%d", &(tenant + i)->phone);

fprintf(file, "Name: %s\nLast name: %s\nFloor: %d\nPhone: 0%d\n", (tenant + i)->fname, (tenant + i)->lname, (tenant + i)->floor, (tenant + i)->phone);
fprintf(file, "\n//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n");

}

void read(FILE* file, int helper, TENANT* tenant)
{

for (int i = 0; i < helper; i++)
{
    fscanf(file, "Name: %s\nLast name: %s\nFloor: %d\nPhone: 0%d\n", (tenant + i)->fname, (tenant + i)->lname, &((tenant + i)->floor), &((tenant + i)->phone));
}
}


int main() {

int n = 0, helper = 1;
char nameFile[100];
TENANT *tenant = NULL;
tenant = (TENANT*)calloc(200, sizeof(TENANT));

FILE *file = NULL;


printf("Name of building: ");
scanf("%s", nameFile);
printf("\n");

while (n != 4) {
    printf("Press 1 for creating file! \n");
    printf("Press 2 for reading from file! \n");
    printf("Press 3 for adding new tenants! \n");
    printf("Press 4 to close the file! \n\n");
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");

    switch (n)
    {
    case 1:
        file = fopen(nameFile, "w");
        printf("File created.\n");
        printf("\n");
        fclose(file);
        break;

    case 2:
        if ((file = fopen(nameFile, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("File is not yet created!\n\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("read");
            read(file, helper++, tenant);

            //after you test your program for reading
            //just delete fprintf :)
            fprintf(stdout, "Name: %s\nLast name: %s\nFloor: %d\nPhone: 0%d\n", tenant[0].fname, tenant[0].lname, tenant[0].floor, tenant[0].phone);
            printf("\n");
            fclose(file);
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        helper++;
        printf("Insert details of tenant: \n");
        file = fopen(nameFile, "a");
        write(file, helper, tenant);
        printf("\n");
        fclose(file);
        break;

    case 4:
        printf("Program closed!\n");
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }
}
free(tenant);
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Be aware you are using variable helper for reading and for writing. Maybe use different variables for this because you wont read from the start of the file if you increment your variable helper while writing in it :)